# Datepicker with events?

Tags: jquery, calendar, datepicker

Is there a jquery plugin that would allow me to have a small calendar like rectangle, like in datepickers and some of the dates would be different colour. When I go over the date with mouse there is a popup saying what event is scheduled on that day. Of course I would populate the event array with events ;-)

All I find are the datepickers (small) or calendars (full screen large). What I need for my webpage is there is a small calendar there and a simple mouseover that would show the text that I would like it to show.

Does something like that exists?

Comment: You can use the [jquery UI datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#inline). It has a rich API with which you can do what you want.

Comment: I have looked at it, but I didn't find option to add popup text to single day.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As others have pointed out, this is possible with jQueryUI's [datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/).

Datepicker has some built in functionality that will help you get there.  Specifically, the [`beforeShowDay`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-beforeShowDay) event will let you customize the appearance and behavior of each day without much code at all:

1. Create an object containing events you can reference from the `datepicker`'s event handler:

   ```
   var Event = function(text, className) {
       this.text = text;
       this.className = className;
   };

   var events = {};
   events[new Date("02/14/2011")] = new Event("Valentines Day", "pink");
   events[new Date("02/18/2011")] = new Event("Payday", "green");
   ```

   This code just creates an object with "keys" being the event date and "values" being event data.
2. To make the `datepicker` widget show up all the time (without requiring an `input` for example), just apply the widget to a `div`:

   **HTML**:

   ```
   <div id="dates"></div>
   ```

   **JavaScript**:

   ```
   $("#dates").datepicker({....});
   ```
3. Tap into the `beforeShowDay` event, and return the appropriate array.  `datepicker` will automatically apply a tooltip and class you specify.  This is where the `Event` objects we defined above come in handy:

   ```
   $("#dates").datepicker({
       beforeShowDay: function(date) {
           var event = events[date];
           if (event) {
               return [true, event.className, event.text];
           }
           else {
               return [true, '', ''];
           }
       }
   });
   ```

   This is probably the trickiest part.  The `beforeShowDay` event handler expects you to return an array structured like this:

   > [ 0 ] equal to true/false indicating
   >   whether or not this date is
   >   selectable, [ 1 ] equal to a CSS class
   >   name(s) or '' for the default
   >   presentation, and [ 2 ] an optional
   >   popup tooltip for this date.

   So what we're doing is looking up the event on the date passed into the function handling the `beforeShowDay` event and returning the data from our event object, if it exists.

It looks like alot, but it's not too bad when you look at it all put together.  Check out the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/rMhVz/1/

Note the CSS classes must use `!important` to override the default background of the `datepicker`, and actually apply to the `a` tags inside of the date `tr`s

Comment: Thanx a lot! Is there a way I would fire some popup (layer window) when clicking on a date with event? Now only tooltip of browser is shown, could you just tell me in which direction to think if I want to call my own popup when clicked? I bought highslide for popups, but I don't know how to fire it in your code.

Comment: Hi @Andrew : How to implement event with datepicker from http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html , I just tried your code but not working. Thanks.

Comment: This is great! You saved my day, I owe you a beer!

Comment: This is awesome. I have a SP calendar that I have some events and would like to populate the Jquery calendar with it. How can I do that? Is there any way I can create the `events` entries using a CAML query?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [jquery UI datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker). With some extra jquery you can hook up a mouseover event and display information.

The dates are recognizable with cssclass and nesting information. After showing the calendar you can attach your eventhandler.

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
         $("input").datepicker();     
   });

   $('td a').live('mouseenter', function () { 
     alert($(this).text() + ' ' + $('.ui-datepicker-month').text() 
                          + ' ' +$('.ui-datepicker-year').text()  );    
   });
```

the selectors need some precision to work correct, but the idea stays the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do something special on a day hover you could attach a .live handler (or delegate), live is needed since the datepicker is created after the dom has finished loading, to the day element and do some sort of lookup if you need to display a tooltip, box, or something else unique on the dom.

```
$(".ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-state-default").live("hover", function() {
    var month = $(".ui-datepicker-month").text();
    var year = $(".ui-datepicker-year").text();
    var day = $(this).text();
    //Do something to look up the year month day..
    $("h1").empty().text(month + day + year).fadeIn();

}, function() {
  //something on mouse out
});
```

Simple example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/XkV44/1/).

However if you find the jQuery UI datepicker does not meet your needs take a look at original [datepicker](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html) plugin which offers a lot of customization.  Plus it also offers a few more events in the datepicker [extension](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html?#extend).

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the jQuery UI datepicker you could check out my datepicker:
http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/

It sounds like what you are looking for is covered by the renderCalendar function:
http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/renderCalendarBankHolidays.html

That example uses a `renderCallback` to add click handlers and extra text to bank holidays. You should be able to easily adjust this to add a hover handler instead.