# Pull in JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui

I am trying to get an event calendar working from json data. I just want to highlight dates, and have a div update below the calendar with the event details when the user clicks on a date. My app serves the JSON in the form:

```
[
  {"Date":"02/06/2012","Title":"Eat, Bike, and Swim"},
  {"Date":"02/03/2012","Title":"Sleep"},
  {"Date":"02/02/2012","Title":"Laugh"}
]
```

I have a JS fiddle that works with a variable definition, but I can't get it to respond to a  JSON request.

Here is my best attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/PGmFv/2/

The javascript is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dp, events;
  events = [];
  return dp = $(".blog_calendar").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      var matching, result;
      $.getJSON("https://raw.github.com/gist/1676157/15ce81851e57dfcecb985039e970a749585959de/my.json", function(data) {
        return events = data;
      });
      result = [true, "", null];
      matching = $.grep(events, function(event) {
        return event.Date.valueOf() === date.valueOf();
      });
      if (matching.length) {
        result = [true, "highlight", null];
      }
      return result;
    },
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
      var date, event, i, selectedDate;
      date = void 0;
      selectedDate = new Date(dateText);
      i = 0;
      event = null;
      while (i < events.length && !event) {
        date = events[i].Date;
        if (selectedDate.valueOf() === date.valueOf()) {
          event = events[i];
        }
        i++;
      }
      if (event) {
        return alert(event.Title);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

I'm trying to load in the json inside the datepicker function because I want to be able to have multiple calendars on the same page and `this.id` contains a specific url variable so I can call `$.getJSON('/events/' + this.id + '/data.json',function() {}`

Any thoughts greatly appreciated. I'm leaning significantly on: [Events in jQuery UI Datepicker with json data source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4017897/events-in-jquery-ui-datepicker-with-json-data-source) and [Datepicker with events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051827/datepicker-with-events) but just not able to get the json to load at the right time and in the right way.

The lack of an error in console is not helping.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to get JSON data from another domain, you have to use JSONP with a callback function. The [Github API](http://developer.github.com/v3/gists/) supports this ([example](https://api.github.com/gists/2439102?callback=loadfromgist)), and jQuery handles making the callback automatically with `dataType: 'jsonp'`.

This is how I get JSON data from a Github gist with jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://api.github.com/gists/'+gistid,
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'jsonp'
}).success( function(gistdata) {
  // This can be less complicated if you know the gist file name
  var objects = [];
  for (file in gistdata.data.files) {
    if (gistdata.data.files.hasOwnProperty(file)) {
      var o = JSON.parse(gistdata.data.files[file].content);
      if (o) {
        objects.push(o);
      }
    }
  }
  if (objects.length > 0) {
    // DoSomethingWith(objects[0])
  }
}).error( function(e) {
  // ajax error
});
```

([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pWGVp/))

Answer (score 1):

Quite a lot of code to dig through, but aren't you making an asynchronous call and then trying to return a value from an anonymous function? Trying to use `events` just after *initiating* getJSON but probably quite a bit *before* the data is actually fetched?

Comment: now this makes sense, but I'm not sure how to fix it. I need to pull in the json data in the datepicker function so I can put multiple calendars on the same page and request an id specific to the calendar div

Comment: I'm trying something like this based on your suggestion, but still not working: http://jsfiddle.net/PGmFv/12/

Answer (score 0):

This error is coming because the request

```
 $.getJSON("https://raw.github.com/gist/1676157/15ce81851e57dfcecb985039e970a749585959de/my.json")
```

is not in same domain.So console.log() shows this error

```
  Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Running $.getJSON('Same domain request')  will cause no error.

See  the fiddle and see console error message.
      http://jsfiddle.net/PGmFv/10/

Comment: thanks, and much appreciated -- I saw that -- so I'm not sure how to get the JSON in to jsfiddle. the bigger issue is the request itself.