# Get Raw Gist File

Tags: javascript, github, gist, same-origin-policy

What I want is simple. Is there any way (including a work around) to make this work?

```
function loadXMLDoc() {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var gistRawFileUrl = 'https://gist.github.com/kentcdodds/5822336/raw/6ef128c8c8d6fe416782d969efa95d36e0acf374/KentsBlog.md';

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
      var gistFileContent = request.responseText;
      doSomethingCool(gistFileContent);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', gistRawFileUrl, true);
  request.send();
}
```

Right now, if I execute this in the console here I'm getting:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://gist.github.com/kentcdodds/5822336/raw/6ef128c8c8d6fe416782d969efa95d36e0acf374/KentsBlog.md. Origin http://stackoverflow.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

This makes sense, and I know I'm not going to get GitHub to open up their access control, but if there's a work around to this or if I'm doing something wrong that would be great.

I realize that you can get the content of the file, by hitting the JSONP endpoint, but that doesn't give you the newline characters, so what was once this:

```
Hello World!
You
Rock!
```

Is now this:

```
Hello World!YouRock!
```

Thanks in advance.

**Edit** The problem with the newlines is something I need to fix on my end, not a Gist thing.

Comment: Possibly this will work? https://github.com/kares/script.js

Comment: I voted to close this because it's not useful for anyone in the future. The problem was unrelated to reading raw gists from github.

Comment: In a comment, OP said that he wanted this closed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10454873/240963

API endpoint will give you content of each file within the Gist, including the formatting. The only downside is that you need to transfer extra data even if you already know the URL for the raw file.

We can simplify the code from the original answer, since you don't want to parse JSON and you probably know the filename:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://api.github.com/gists/'+gistid,
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'jsonp'
}).success( function(gistdata) {
    var content = gistdata.data.files[filename].content;
    DoSomethingWith(content)
  }).error( function(e) {
  // ajax error
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J4n7u/2/)

Using JSONP with raw XHR is a bit more complicated, but you could use [something lighter](http://microjs.com/#ajax) than jQuery.

Comment: In my question, I explain that the content property of the file doesn't have newlines...

Comment: Newlines are escaped as \n, as you can see: https://api.github.com/gists/cde117d171aeb720cbc6?callback=loadfromgist – also notice that new lines are restored in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/J4n7u/3/ Newlines should be parsed automatically within JSONP, even without jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/whGrY/

Comment: I apologize, you are absolutely correct. The newlines was a different problem that I *can* fix. Thanks!