# Function this.text=text; to html

Tags: php, jquery

I have some code for a tootlip in a calendar. i want to be able to display html in the tool tip is this possible? every time i try and change it to accept html it crashes it only allows text right now and i do not understand how to change it to allow for html

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
          <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
          <title></title>

          <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js'></script>

          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css">
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">


              <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
              <script type='text/javascript' src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>


          <style type='text/css'>
            .pink > a {
            background-color: pink !important;
            background-image:none !important;
        }

        .green > a {
            background-color: green !important;
            background-image: none !important;
        }

          </style>



        <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
        $(window).load(function(){
        var Event = function(text, className) {
            // would like to convert this to allow for html
            this.text = text;
            // this.html = text; // does not work
            this.className = className;
        };

        var events = {};
        events[new Date("01/01/2013")] = new Event("New Years Day", "pink");
        events[new Date("12/25/2012")] = new Event("<B>Merry</b> Christmas", "green");

        console.dir(events);

        $("#dates").datepicker({
            beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                var event = events[date];
                if (event) {
                    return [true, event.className, event.text];
                }
                else {
                    return [true, '', ''];
                }
            }
        });
        });//]]>

        </script>


        </head>
        <body>
          <div id="dates"></div>


        </body>


        </html>
```

thank you in advance for any code or help you may provide

Johnny

Comment: what exactly are you asking?

Comment: how to change the tooltip to display html, so it makes the merry bold in the <b>Merry</b> Christmas string

Comment: darn wont let me paste code to a comment or i dont know how to at least. first time i've used stackoverflow.com

Comment: You shouldn't use event as a variable name. It's a reserved word in Javascript.

Comment: Well sorry, cant really help you.

Comment: @tomrozendaal not my code, just trying to make a calendar with event tooltip with html in the tooltip

Comment: Tooltips can't contain *any* HTML; they can, and can *only*, display unformatted strings. Since you're using jQuery anyway you have access to [several plugins](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=javascript+tooltip+plugin) that can help with this, though.

Comment: this is where i got the code from for this mini calendar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051827/datepicker-with-events

Comment: @ David Thomas sorry not true about html in tooltips see for ref http://familiesinchrist.org/calendar_lcw_google.php

Comment: Yes, that's using a plugin, [jQuery qTip plugin](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/) to be precise; and somewhat supports my original assertion.

Comment: @DavidThomas sorry its not using qtip plugin,(code has been revised to not have qtip js in scripts section) full calendar had its own built in tooltip and on hover functions, forgot now its been a while but lets get past this. so i cant just convert the text to html via something like .html ok thats fine.  i dont know how to convert this project to utilize a plugin any help to display html would be great please looking for bold(strong) and color in tool tip thank you

Comment: @Johnny you are technically correct - they're now using fancydropdown.js rather than qtip - but that's absolutely no call to be dismissive of someone who's trying to help you by explaining how things work, especially when he was actually correct on his earlier point (which you were dismissive of then).  I assume that you are not a native English speaker.  You should know that statements that take the form "sorry, you're wrong" are dismissive and somewhat rude - especially when you don't actually know what you're talking about.

Comment: sorry was not trying to be rude at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The title attribute does not allow html code.

But there are several frameworks out there that allow you to modify the hover.

I used [jQuery Tooltip](http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/)

```
<script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/jquery.tooltip.js"></script>
$('*').tooltip();
```

Here you will see that they tooltip has been modified and the bold is in place.

http://jsfiddle.net/Morlock0821/WqrMK/

Comment: this is what i was looking for, the example is prefect, im grateful others pointed out it needed a plugin thank you as well, i picked this solution as it has an example of how to accomplish fixing the problem again thank you all for the input and comments